# DataGridView bound to MS Access table with Autonumber Primary key causes Concurrency errors

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

A have a volunteer timesheet data entry system which allows the volunteers to enter the times they have spent on various activities. I used the VB.net Designer to create the system (OK, I know now that that was not a good move!) so please don't ask me to show my code, most of it is generated by the Designer. My problem is this: 
Each new record is assigned a negative number as a primary key when it is entered which is the way a dgv works with Access Automumber keys. I am executing the following statements in the RowValidating event when the row is valid.

```
   a_dgv.EndEdit()
    a_dgv.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
    Me.TimeSheets2BindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.MembershipDataSet)
```

This code does not update the primary key value on the dgv although it does so in the Access table. If a user then attempts to delete or alter a record he has earlier added in the same session the update fails with a concurrency error. The only answer if have found to this problem is to refill the whole table. This is obviously not a desirable solution. Does anyone have a proven tested one?

I should probably mention that my table has two databound comboboxes

Comment: What you need to do is retrieve the ID generated by Access when you save the data and update the `DataTable` with that value. This is simpler with databases that support multiple SQL statements per command, e.g. SQL Server, where you can just add a `SELECT` statement to the end of the `INSERT`. With Access, you have to write a bit of VB code. Check [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?659052) out to learn how.

Comment: I would also suggest that you change that code, getting rid of the first two lines and replacing them with a call to the form's `Validate` method.

Comment: Thanks very much for this jmcilhinney. This information seems to have solved my problem although much additional testing will be needed before I am absolutely certain

Answer (score 0):

I was under the impression that a datagrid that is the result of a dataset from say Access does not show the PK values as -1, -2, -3.

If you created the disconnected dataset (or datatable) in code from a fill (pull data from Access), then each row normally does not show the PK.

However, regardless of the above, assuming you entered 5 rows, and now need to see the PK values?

You will during data entry in the grid should see this:

[image]

In above, I have added two rows. Your save code is somewhat like this:

```
    tblHotels = DataGridView1.DataSource

    rstDataReader.Update(tblHotels)
    tblHotels.AcceptChanges()
```

That will send the data back to SQL server (or Access), and the autonumber PK 'ids are then generated. However, such changes are NOT pulled back into the dataset/datatable. In other words, the PK id's are generated in the database, but UNLESS you re-pull the data, you are not going to see the PK values.

You WILL have to re-pull the data. However, you can keep the current position of the grid, and re-fill the data like this:

```
    rstDataReader.Update(tblHotels)
    tblHotels.AcceptChanges()
    Dim MyTop As Integer = DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex
    tblHotels.Clear()
    rstDataReader.Fill(tblHotels)
    DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = MyTop
```

And then you should see this:

[image]

The other way would be to send + update each row as you edit data, and then pull the PK, but obvious then you not be able to update the all your grid changes with a SAVE button, and thus of course no un-do ability.

I find the above that re-positions the top of the grid does not flicker. On the other hand, I suppose this could/would depend on how large the data set is (but then again, loading up a grid with too many rows is less then ideal).

So, as far as I can tell, you have to re-pull the dataset/datatable to get the new generated PK id's, or you have to save + pull for each row you edit. For a gridview with even several 100 rows, I don't see any flicker with the above code.

Comment: Thanks for taking the trouble to reply. When I make my TimesheetID field visible in the DataGridView I do see the negative primary key values that the dgv generates, -1, -2, etc. What I was seeking was a more efficient method than refilling the table.

Comment: There is not much you can do, but since such a grid should not and will have much data, then the re-fresh should not be a problem. If there is a large numbers of rows in such a grid, then allowing inserts to that data is a less then ideal design, and you find few if any UI designs allow as such.  I mean, how many lines of data can you expect say on a typical invoice? So, once you have say close to a page of data, then a different UI is required. About the only exception to this UI approach is Excel, but then again we all know how amazing bad Excel is when people try to use it as a database.